# Prevent parent's event on child node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, events, dom-events

I try to modify a legacy code table that was made on react, the table consist of rows and cells and looks like:

```
<Table>
   <Row onClick={rowClickHandler}>
      <Cell onCLick={cellClickHandler} />
      <Cell />
      <Cell/>
   </Row>
   <Row onClick={rowClickHandler}>
      <Cell onCLick={cellClickHandler} />
      <Cell />
      <Cell/>
   </Row>
   <Row onClick={rowClickHandler}>
      <Cell onCLick={cellClickHandler} />
      <Cell />
      <Cell/>
   </Row>
</Table>
```

The rows have their own click handler (`rowClickHandler`) and the first column cells have their own (`cellClickHandler`).

The main problem I faced is the event propagation, when I click on the first column cell I want only its handler work, but the row's handler works as well. I've already tried `StopPropagation`, but it also stops the handler of the child node (`cellClickHandler`).

I don't have an opportunity to change the layout, I need to prevent the parent's handler on the child node. How to do it?

Approximate image:

[image]

Comment: If you don't want your row-onclick to fire when clicking inside the row's elements, when do you want it to fire?

Comment: Its stopPropagation(). You're probably causing an error if you use the wrong casing. Check the console log.

Comment: SHOW THE CODE..... Show the JavaScript code that did not work

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation is the way to go, but instead of setting up handlers for the cells and rows, just set up one handler on the `table` and in that handler, determine what element triggered the event with `event.target.nodeName` and then just respond accordingly.

Here's an example:

```js
document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  let node = event.target.nodeName;
  
  switch (node){
    case "TABLE":
      console.log("You clicked the table!");
      break;
    case "TR":
      console.log("You clicked the row!");
      break;    
    case "TD":
      console.log("You clicked the cell!");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("You clicked the " + event.target.nodeName + "!");
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
table { border:15px solid red; }
tr { border:5px solid green; }
td { border:5px solid blue; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 1, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2, Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 2, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3, <button>Click me</button> Column 1</td>
    <td>Row 3, Column 2</td>
    <td>Row 3, Column 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```